# Почему при работе с Яндекс.переводчиком я получаю ошибку "heder is not defended"?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2, яндекс-переводчик

Пытаюсь получить ответ от Яндекс.Переводчика. Или не срабатывает скрипт, или некорректный запрос. И даже непонятно где ошибка:

> heder is not defended.

В консоли: ничего не выводит, и даже до того места не доходит.

[Онлайн](http://jsbin.com/sejupidabi/edit?html,js,console,output).

```js
var app = angular.module('jsbin', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.SendData = function() {
    // тут данные
    var textApi = 'Hello';
    var langApi = 'en-ru';
    var text1 = 'Hello';
    var params = "key=" + keyAPI + "&text=" + textApi + "&lang=" + langApi;
    var url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate";
    var keyAPI = "trnsl.1.1.20130922T110455Z.4a9208e68c61a760.f819c1db302ba637c2bea1befa4db9f784e9fbb8";
    var vm = this;

    $http({
        url: url,
        method: 'POST',
        params: params
      })
      .success(function(data, headers, status, config) {
        $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
        vm.data = data;
        console.log(data);
      })
      .error(function(data, headers, status, config) {
        $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
          "<hr />status: " + status +
          "<hr />headers: " + header +
          "<hr />config: " + config;
      })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="jsbin">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">
    <button ng-click="SendData()">Send</button>
    <br>Data: {{PostDataResponse}}
    <br>{{vm.data}} {{vm.PostDataResponse}} Data: {{scope.PostDataResponse}} {{vm.data}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно, параметры это объекты. Спасибо.
ВОт рабочий вариант:

```js
var app = angular.module('jsbin', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl',function($scope, $http){
    
    $scope.SendData = function () {
          // тут данные
      var textApi='Hello';
      var langApi='en-ru';
       var url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?";
    var  keyAPI ="trnsl.1.1.20161125T152027Z.65e73e18a60f3051.7764a7a11754995544ad557501df9e14abbfb6e0";
  
       
    var vm = this;
       $scope.method = 'POST';
    $scope.url = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?';  
      
     $http({
   url: url,
   method:"POST",
   params:{key:keyAPI,text:textApi,lang:langApi},
})
.success(function(data,headers,status,config){
  $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
  vm.data = data;
  console.log(data);
 })
.error(function(data,headers,status,config){
 $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                "<hr />status: " + status +
                     "<hr />config: " + config;
       console.log("error1");
       console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
       console.log(config)
     }
)
}
}
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular JS</title>
   </head>
<body ng-app="jsbin">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as vm">
    
          <button ng-click="SendData()">Send</button>
    <br>
      Data:  {{PostDataResponse}}<br>
    {{vm.data}}
    {{vm.PostDataResponse}}
   Data:  {{scope.PostDataResponse}}
    {{vm.data}}
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: пожалуйста не забудьте [отметить Ваш ответ как решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку под цифрой слева от ответа. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как [решение вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> И даже непонятно где ошибка heder is not defended.

На самом деле понятно: в метод `error` передается функция с параметрами

```
function(data,headers,status,config){
```

Стоит обратить внимание, что вторым параметром является `headers`

В теле же функции происходит попытка обращения к `header`

```
$scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
            "<hr />status: " + status +
            "<hr />headers: " + header + // вот эта строка!
            "<hr />config: " + config;
```

Как видно, такой переменной действительно нет.

Comment: Точно. Но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит.

Comment: @Dmitry, почему не происходит? происходит идет запросу к яндексу, он говорит что плохой apiKey, посылает статус 403, ты попадаешь в обработчик `error`, пытаешься его выполнить и падаешь при попытке получить значение необъявленной переменной, о чем и получаешь сообщение в консоли.

Comment: Действительно.  Но фишка в том, что ключ был получен и скопирован.  Сейчас получил еще один-тоже самое. http://jsbin.com/sejupidabi/edit?html,js,console,output